# Как получить из многомерного списка, обычный?

Tags: python, list, numpy

Есть многомерный список:

```
[array([[309.54673127],
        [309.54731989],
        [309.54790851],
        ...,
        [338.97611443],
        [338.97670305],
        [338.97729168]]),
 array([[291.43137723],
        [291.43269454],
        [291.43401186],
        ...,
        [357.29307209],
        [357.2943894 ],
        [357.29570671]]),
 array([[353.57357309],
        [353.5769884 ],
        [353.58040371],
```

Как его превратить просто в `list`?

```
list = [309.54673127, 309.54731989, 309.54790851 ... 291.43137723, 291.43269454, 291.43401186 ...]
```

Comment: `array` - это объект Numpy?

Comment: можете показать участок кода, где вы делаете `append`? Там будет проще и элегантнее всего это сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сделайте вместо:

```
res = []
for ... :
    res.append(func(...))
```

так:

```
res = np.concatenate([np.ravel(func(...)) for ...])
```

---

**UPD:** упрощенный вариант:

```
final = np.array([])
for ...:
    temp = ...
    final = np.concatenate([final, np.ravel(temp)])
```

#### Пояснение:

- [np.ravel()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) - превращает N-размерную матрицу в одномерный вектор.
- [np.concatenate()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) - объединяет несколько Numpу объектов в один.

В итоге получаем одномерный вектор результатов. Если нужно получить Vanilla Python список, то можно воспользоваться методом `res.tolist()`

Comment: @Анжелика, поэтому я и просил привести в вопросе релевантный участок кода ;) Как вы получаете `temp`?

Comment: @Анжелика, оберните "очень большой код" в функцию `func` и воспользуйтесь решением из моего ответа)

Comment: @Анжелика, можно, если пожертвовать принципами правильного написания кода и производительностью... Дополнил ответ простым, но топорным решением...